# python range syntax for array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, range

I'm trying to slice a 3d array with python.

```
data = np.zeros((150, 3, 25))
for i in range (1, 26):
    data2[:,:,i] = data[:, i*3-1:i*3+2]
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

```
IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 25
```

I'm new to python, but my understanding of the range syntax is that the first number is inclusive, but the last number is exclusive. Because `data` is a 150*3*25 array, and I want this command to affect all pages 1 through 25, should't I be able to slice with this command? Sorry if this is a simple mistake -- I'm new to python. It would be great if anyone could help.

I'm running python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Python indexes from 0, so when you reach 25 for `i` when iterating, you attempt to index the 25th element in an axis you allocated space for only 25 elements.

So either make `data = np.zeros((150, 3, 26))` or change your range to `range(1, 25)`.